# AutoComplete/Sugestões/MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Pergunta 1: Alguém tem algum exemplo funcional de quando alguém digita em um input aparece sugestões abaixo? de preferência vindo de uma tabela criada no mysql.

> Banco: teste 
>   Tabela: usuarios (user_id, user_email).

Pergunta2:
Em um "option value" como eu poderia fazer pra ordenar em ordem decrescente?
 A partir disto:

```html
  <td class="KT_th"><label for="user_id">Nome de Usuário:</label></td>
  <td><select name="user_id" id="user_id">
    <?php
do {  
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_Rsmostrar['user_id']?>"<?php if (!(strcmp($row_Rsmostrar['user_id'], $row_Rsmostrar['user_nome']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row_Rsmostrar['user_nome']?></option>
    <?php
} while ($row_Rsmostrar = mysql_fetch_assoc($Rsmostrar));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($Rsmostrar);
  if($rows > 0) {
  mysql_data_seek($Rsmostrar, 0);
  $row_Rsmostrar = mysql_fetch_assoc($Rsmostrar);
  }
?>
```

Comment: Talvez implementar o jQuery-ui Autocomplete seria uma boa saída.

Answer (score 0):

1 pergunta, voce poderia usar mesmo o Jquery UI, como o @dvd falou.

2 pergunta, para pegar em ordem decrescente, faça essa lógica

```
$listaUsuarios = //array de usuarios da tabela;

$amount = count($listaUsuarios); //quantidade de usuarios

for ($i = $amount; $i >= $amount; $i--) {
    //aqui voce faz a logica do <select>
    <option>
        echo $listaUsuarios[$i]; //vai fazer na ordem decrescente
    </option>
}
```

Só uma lógica, você implementa o seu

Aqui está o Jquery UI: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/